# $q with private $$state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

When using Angular's $q why is everything held under the $$state object?  I was under the impression that double dollar meant private in Angular, which doesn't quite make sense to me in this context.  Have I implemented my promise incorrectly?

Just testing, this returns object with $$state:

```
$scope.makePromise = function(){
  return $q(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve('Promise Resolved');
  });
}
```

Comment: You promise is correct. As doc says: it's constructor for ES6 promise.

Comment: What  else would you expect it to return?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `$$state` is how Angular keeps track of the internal state of its promises. You're not supposed to use it in your own code and it can break in the future.

Instead, if you want to check the state of the promise - you should add a `then` handler to it:

```
myPromise.then(function(el){
    // I got here after the promise resolved and `el` is the value
    // it fulfilled with.
}, function(e){
    // I got here after the promise rejected and `e` is the error
    // it rejected with.
});
```